# NPM Self Published Component cannot be found when using it in a React Project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm-install, package.json

I created my own React component and published it for use. 
I just finished minifying for distribution and routing that through webpack.
(Babel used to just transpile and copy all files to dist).

however I now can't seem to import it for my projects anymore.

I install like: 
`npm i react-subreddit-posts`

and then import like:

`import SubredditPosts from 'react-subreddit-posts';`

And then get this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-subreddit-posts'
```

so I must be exporting the module wrong or minifying it wrong???

Here is the source code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ListContainer from './ListContainer';
import ListItemComponent from './ListItemComponent';

const redditAPI = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/';

export default class SubredditPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      redditPosts: [],
      isLoading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const uri = `${redditAPI}${this.props.subreddit}.json`;
    fetch(uri)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(this.handlePosts)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  handlePosts = (posts) => {
    const apiPosts = posts.data.children.map((post, index) => {
      return {
        key: index,
        title: post.data.title,
        media: this.getMediaFromPost(post),
        link: post.data.url
      };
    });

    this.setState({
      redditPosts: apiPosts,
      isLoading: false
     });
  }

  getMediaFromPost = (post) => {
    const extension = post.data.url.split('.').pop();

    if (post.data.hasOwnProperty('preview') &&  !extension.includes('gif')) {
      return post.data.preview.images[0].source.url;
    }

    //do not use includes! because of Imgur's gifv links are not embeddable
    if (extension === 'gif' || extension.includes('jpg') ||  extension.includes('jpeg')) {
      return post.data.url;
    }

    //if can't load media then place placeholder
    return this.props.placeholder;
  }

    render() {
      return(
        <ListContainer display={this.props.display}>
        { !this.state.isLoading && this.state.redditPosts.map(post => (
          <ListItemComponent
            display={this.props.display}
            key={post.key}
            link={post.link}
            media={post.media}
            title={post.title}
            height={this.props.height}
            width={this.props.width}
          />
        ))}
        </ListContainer>
      );
    }
}
```

Here is what is in `node_modules` after install through npm: 
[image]

I can export it just fine from the src, but not when it's published and distributed!

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-subreddit-posts",
  "version": "1.0.12",
  "description": "React component for displaying subreddit posts in different styles",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/stcalica/react-subreddit-posts"
  },
  "directories": {
    "example": "example"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "transpile": "rm -rf dist && webpack",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run transpile",
    "compile": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --progress"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./test/setupTest.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "reddit"
  ],
  "author": "Kyle Calica",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
// const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
//   template: path.join(__dirname, 'example/src/index.html'),
//   filename: './index.html'
// });

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'example/src/index.js'),
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['react'],
              plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  // plugins: [ htmlWebpackPlugin ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3001
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your github I saw that you have the dist path in your .gitignore file but if you see your package.json you would see that your repo is pointing to the dist/index.js file which does not exist because you added it to the .gitignore.

Try:

- Remove the exclusion in your gitignore
- Recompile your app and create the dist folder
- Publish it again in npm
- Re-download your dependency by npm/yarn install
- And make sure you got the latest version of your dependency

Comment: i thought .gitignore and .npmignore would be treated differently. It's definitely there as you can see in the image i just posted in my update. But your right i have `dist/index.js` when my webpack outputs a `main.js`. i'm going to hand edit the node_module install and see if that fixes my problem.

Comment: now I get this error after a minified error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.` any ideas? I'm thinking I'm still exporting wrong maybe?

Comment: is it cause I minified it, that it now can't see `SubredditPosts`?

Comment: Yes, It is because the way you are compiling the library, you are compiling to an IEFF but webpack is actually expecting a library in one of the following module format:  CommonJs, AMD, ES6 modules.

I would try compiling the code right away with webpack instead of just babel with the following configuration:

output.libraryTarget = 'commonjs2';

Comment: And configuring externals, check one configuration that I wrote a long time ago https://github.com/miguelcrespo/react-progressive-loading/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: could you explain the difference and etc?

Comment: Difference about?

Comment: i mean between IEFF, CommonJS and etc. I don't have that line in my `webpack` or my `package.json`. Am I adding ` configuration: output.libraryTarget = 'commonjs2';` to which one of those files and what does that do exactly?

Comment: Is IEFF the default then? Since I didn't specify anything in webpack.                                                                                                                              
Best documentation I could find was this: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputlibrary